# Teradata 'like any' for Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a similar function `like any` which is in Teradata available in Postgresql?

```
select * from product
where proc_cd like any ('20','23','05','06','07','08','22')
```

Comment: Looks like a different way to write: `proc_cd in ('20','23','05','06','07','08','22')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As near as I can tell (sorry, Teradata's official documentation server appears to be down at the moment), this in Teradata:

```
proc_cd like any ('20','23','05','06','07','08','22')
```

is just short for:

```
proc_cd like '20' or proc_cd like '23' or proc_cd like '05' ...
```

PostgreSQL has a more general [`ANY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.28.16) that allows you to say:

```
expression operator ANY (array expression)
```

for any `operator` such as `=`, `LIKE`, etc. So you could just convert that list to an array and say:

```
proc_cd like any (array['20','23','05','06','07','08','22'])
```

Comment: As there are no wildcards involved, isn't that exactly the same as `in ('20','23','05','06','07','08','22')`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm assuming that we just have an example that just happens to not use any pattern matching. Otherwise you'd probably write it as `in (list)` in Teradata as well (unless there is something special with Teradata's LIKE or ANY that we don't know about). Of course, Teradata's doc server seems to be having database problems (ha ha) so I can't check.

Comment: Teradata is special. It allows to use wildcards for example `where dsc_item like any ('%DOG CHOW%','%PEDIGREE%','%BENEFUL%')`

Comment: @LukaszSzozda: that's possible with Postgres as well: `like any (array['%dog%','%cat%'])`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That is really nice syntax :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `JOIN`(useful if wildcards like `_` or `%` are present):

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.*
FROM Product p
JOIN (VALUES ('20'),('23'),('05'),('06'),('07'),('08'),('22')) sub(s)
  ON proc_cd like LIKE sub.s;
```

Alternatively (if no wildcards):

```
select * from product
where proc_cd IN ('20','23','05','06','07','08','22');

select * from product
where proc_cd = any (ARRAY['20','23','05','06','07','08','22']);
```

Comment: (1) You need parentheses when using `any`: `any(array[...])`. (2) PostgreSQL's `any` is quite general allows you to say `expr op any(array_expr)` for any binary operator `op`.